# How to query for a list of RDF triples using SPARQL?

Tags: java, list, sparql

I have an RDF database (AFAIK) where I store Java objects which are mapped to RDF triples.

What I want to do now is query for a list of all objects of a specific type.

I imagine something like this, where I have put in my imagination of the syntax:

```
PREFIX xyz: <http://foo.com/myclassname#>
SELECT *
WHERE {
  xyz:* name ?name
}
```

I want to say that I want all triples which represent names of the subject with type myclassname. How to do this correctly?

Right now I can't give you error messages, because I do not have a running system, but I'm sure I do not understand SPARQL queries well enough, so please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

SPARQL queries are generally in the form `?subject ?predicate ?object`. So you need to run a simple query like this to know if you need to put your restriction in the place of `?Predicate` or you need to add another triple (`?object ?x ?y`) to your query. Please refer to [SPARQL for begginers](https://code.google.com/p/tdwg-rdf/wiki/Beginners6SPARQL) for more examples.

Your answer in short is that yes, you can query based on a specific type, but you need to know where to put this type restriction.

So for example in DBpedia if you want to get the labels of everything you can say:

```
select distinct *
where 
    {?s rdfs:label ?o}
LIMIT 100
```

If you want this label to be a name, you need to specify the type of your object:

```
select distinct *
where 
    {?s rdfs:label ?o.
    ?s a dbpedia-owl:Person}
 LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I definitely need to put the restriction to subject, because predicate (e.g. "name") and object (e.g. "Foo") can be equal for different types of objects. Thus, the type information can be found only in the subject.

Comment: So you already know where to look. Just in your query only ask for all the distinct ?subjects and then you know what type you are looking for.

Comment: Artemis: my problem is about the SPARQL **syntax**: I know what I want, but I don't know how to express that in SPARQL.

Comment: I don't know how your triple store is arranges, but added some queries for you to try on DBpedia to see what I was trying to explain.

Answer (score 1):

The exact syntax of the SPARQL query depends on how exactly your data is modeled in RDF. Let's assume that objects of a class `MyClass` are represented as follows in your RDF database, and that they have a name property `my:name`:

```
@prefix my: <http://example.org/my/> .

my:object1 a my:MyClass . 
my:object1 my:name "object 1" .
```

A query to get back all objects and their names modeled in this exact fashion would look like this:

```
PREFIX my: <http://example.org/my/>

SELECT ?x ?name
WHERE { 
     ?x rdf:type my:MyClass ;
        my:name ?name .
}
```

SPARQL queries work as *graph pattern matchers*: the query looks for any combination of *triples* matching the pattern specified in the WHERE-clause: so we're looking for two triples, one expressing that the `rdf:type` property has the value `my:MyClass`, and one expressing that another triple with the same subject should have a property called `my:name`, of which we want back the value (bound to the variable `?name`).

As you can see, it's dependent on your specific RDF model: in your database, the name of the class (`my:MyName`) and the name of the property (`my:name`) are probably different. So you will need to find out how exactly your data is modeled as RDF before you can write a query that works in your specific case.

**Edit** as an aside: SPARQL has a shorthand notation for the property `rdf:type`, which is `a`. So the bit `?x rdf:type my:MyClass` is often written as `?x a my:MyClass`. I wanted to stress the fact that you are querying triples/properties, which is why I used the actual property name.